# Need some help to convert SQL query to Laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM books WHERE id IN
(SELECT book_id FROM `author_book` WHERE author_book.author_id IN 
        (SELECT id FROM authors WHERE  self_name like "%ори%" OR father_name LIKE "%ори%" OR family_name LIKE "%ори%"))
```

It works, but I need convert to Laravel eloquent.
I try this:

```
DB::select("SELECT * FROM books WHERE id IN "
. "(SELECT book_id FROM `author_book` WHERE author_book.author_id IN "
. "(SELECT id FROM authors WHERE  self_name like '%" . $attributes['search'] . "%' "
. "OR father_name LIKE '%" . $attributes['search'] . "%' "
. "OR family_name LIKE '%" . $attributes['search'] . "%'))");
```

And this works, but can't use pagination. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Do you have models for `books`, `author_book` and `author` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want Eloquent solution, use the [`whereHas()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) method:

```
Book::whereHas('authors', function($q) use($search) {
    $q->where('self_name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
      ->orWhere('father_name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
      ->orWhere('family_name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
})->get();
```

This will work if you properly defined relationships. In the `Book` model:

```
public function authors()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Author::class);
}
```

And in the `Author` model:

```
public function books()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Book::class);
}
```