# Need help to convert SQL query to Laravel eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `id` IN(
    SELECT  DISTINCT if(`sender_id`='2',`receiver_id` ,`sender_id`) AS `id`
    FROM    `message`
    WHERE   (`receiver_id`  = '2' OR `sender_id` = '2')
    )
```

I need convert to Laravel eloquent. The problem is, I do not know how to convert the IF function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need some help to convert SQL query to Laravel eloquent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48325545/need-some-help-to-convert-sql-query-to-laravel-eloquent)

Comment: I already seen that @MasivuyeCokile , but can't convert the IF function

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the question with your specific problem not be being able to convert the IF function. Please add the current attempt at converting if you can. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
User::whereIn('id', Message::distinct()->select(DB::raw('if(sender_id=2, receiver_id, sender_id) as id'))->where( 
            function( $query ) {
                $query
                ->where('receiver_id', 2)
                ->orWhere('sender_id', '2');
            }
        ))->toSql();
```

to use if condition in sql statement you can use [DB::raw](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#raw-expressions) method :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$subquery = DB::table('message')
    ->selectRaw("if(sender_id = ?, receiver_id, sender_id) AS id")
    ->distinct()
    ->where(function($query){
        $query
            ->where('receiver_id', '?')
            ->orWhere('sender_id', '?');
    })
    ->toSql();

$query = DB::table('user')
    ->whereRaw('id IN (' . $subquery . ')', [2, 2, 2])
    ->get();
```

[image]